# After doing `:e!`, can I go back in the buffer history?

Tags: vim

As the title states, can I go back in a buffer history even after running `:e!`?

Comment: This question and answer make no sense to me. 'Can I use undo after `:e!`? Yes I can.' What's the point?

Comment: @glts Just my brain taking a day off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`u`

Yep, it's that easy. Thanks to #vim.